# __getattr__ with __import__ from folder in folder isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have no idea what changed, but the following code was working in my project before, and now it's not:

```py
# From Imports
from loguru import logger
from mm import colorize
from sys import exit
from typing import Callable, Any

ls: Callable[..., Any] = logger.success
li: Callable[..., Any] = logger.info
le: Callable[..., Any] = logger.error


# Results in a recursive import if in "mm", as the type_classes files import "mm" as well
def run_backup_type_functions(
    d, func, use_base, *args, **kwargs
) -> None:
    try:
        #############################################
        backup_type_folder: type = getattr(
            __import__("type_classes"), d.backup_type
        )
        #############################################
        backup_type_file: type = getattr(
            backup_type_folder, d.backup_type
        )
        argument_class: type = getattr(
            backup_type_file,
            "base" if use_base else d.argument,
            None,
        )(d, *args, **kwargs)
        getattr(argument_class, func)()
    except TypeError:
        if use_base:
            le(colorize("red", "Sorry; no base exists!"))
        else:
            le(
                colorize("red", 'Sorry; no argument "')
                + colorize("pink", a)
                + colorize("red", '"!')
            )
        exit(1)
    except Exception as e:
        le(
            colorize(
                "red",
                "Sorry; something happened! This was the error:\n\n",
            )
            + colorize("pink", e)
            + "\n"
        )
        exit(1)


def get_backup_type_attr(d, attr, use_base) -> Any:
    try:
        backup_type_folder: type = getattr(
            __import__("type_classes"), d.backup_type
        )
        backup_type_file: type = getattr(
            backup_type_folder, d.backup_type
        )
        argument_class: type = getattr(
            backup_type_file,
            "base" if use_base else d.argument,
            None,
        )(d)
        getattr(argument_class, func)()
    except TypeError:
        if use_base:
            le(colorize("red", "Sorry; no base exists!"))
        else:
            le(
                colorize("red", 'Sorry; no argument "')
                + colorize("pink", a)
                + colorize("red", '"!')
            )
        exit(1)
    except Exception as e:
        le(
            colorize(
                "red",
                "Sorry; something happened! This was the error:\n\n",
            )
            + colorize("pink", e)
            + "\n"
        )
        exit(1)
```

Specifically, the error is `AttributeError: module 'type_classes' has no attribute 'borg'` in `run_backup_type_function` when dynamically importing the `type_classes` subfolder as a module from the parent directory file `mm2.py`, with the `d.backup_type` variable holding the subfolder to be imported; this is shown in the hashed off area of the code. My source directory tree looks like this:

```py
.
├── create.py
├── docker_cmd.py
├── __init__.py
├── LICENSE
├── meltan.py
├── mm2.py
├── mm.py
├── pull.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── regular_cmd.py
├── start.sh
├── test2.py
├── test2.sh
├── test.py
├── tests
├── test.sh
├── tmp
├── total_cmd.py
└── type_classes
    ├── borg
    │   ├── borg.py
    │   ├── Dockerfile
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       └── borg.cpython-37.pyc
    ├── git
    │   └── git.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── mercurial
    │   └── hg.py
    └── __pycache__
        ├── borg.pypy3-71.pyc
        ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
        ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
        └── __init__.pypy3-71.pyc


5 directories, 10 files
```

with nothing in the `type_classes/__init__.py` file. I've tried putting `from borg import borg` in the `type_classes/__init__.py` file as well, but the folder doesn't register, which I think is what is happening for the original issue as well; in addition, I've tried moving the file from inside `borg` to its parent directory, i.e. `type_classes`, but that it gives the same `AttributeError`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I switched to appending the module path to the python path, and importing the sub-module from there:

```py
sys_path.append(
    fullpath(
        os_path.dirname(__file__),
        "type_classes",
        d.backup_type,
    )
)
argument_class: type = getattr(
    __import__(f"mm_{d.backup_type}"),
    "base" if use_base else d.argument,
    None,
)(d, *args, **kwargs)
getattr(argument_class, func)()
```